# Get classes derived from specific class in the module

Tags: python, python-2.7, superclass

I need to get classes from the module that derives only from specific TargetClass:

```
import mymodule as t
for att in dir(t):
   someclass = getattr(t, att)
   if isinstance(someclass, TargetClass):
       print ("Do something with %s" % att)
```

Well... This is not work, so i need to create instances, and catching exceptions, if module's attribute is not callable:

```
import mymodule as t
for att in dir(t):
   someclass = getattr(t, att)
   try:
       if isinstance(someclass(), TargetClass):
           print ("Do something with %s" % att)
   except:
       pass
```

So how do i get only those classes from mymodule, that is subclasses of some TargetClass, without creation of instances and catching exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `issubclass` instead of `isinstance`,
but essentially you'll have the same problem, as the 1st argument to `issubclass` must be a class. So you can combine them:

```
import mymodule as t
for att in dir(t):
   someclass = getattr(t, att)
   if isinstance (someclass, type) and issubclass(someclass, TargetClass):
       print ("Do something with %s" % att)
```

Comment: There are anyway need to catch exceptions: because it can raise something like: "issubclass() arg 1 must be a class" :)

Comment: @RaSergiy I think I accounted for that in the edit soon after posting the answer. Or am I missing something? Maybe you meant to comment on the other answer :)

Comment: isinstance (someclass, type) doesn't work, there is must be instance: isinstance (someclass(), type) ... so the object is created anyway...

Comment: i think there must be only issubclass with exception catching.

Comment: @RaSergiy No, I think `isinstance (someclass, type)` works, but only on new-style classes, because old-style classes are not instances of `type`, but rather `classobj`. There's nothing bad in trying and catching an exception, though. But please avoid using `except` without specifying the sort of exception expected.

Comment: The problem is that module namespace can contains anything, if it imports something from the other modules...

Comment: Ok. Accepted. But i thought there is some more elegant way to do this:)

Comment: @RaSergiy Using `try-except` is considered pythonic: [`EAFP`](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp). So `try` + `issubclass` + `except TypeError` is probably the simplest, given the old-style class problem.

Comment: Thanks, i thought i should avoid try-except statements))